# R package present in library, but still not found when required to install other packages

Tags: r, bioconductor

I need to work with R package **ChaMP**, for which I need to install **DMRcate**, for which I need **IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19**. I have installed "IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19", and it's present in the library location.
When I give the command:

```
library("IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19")
```

it works.

But when I try to install "DMRcate" using BiocManager:

```
BiocManager::install('DMRcate')
```

it shows this:

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.13 (BiocManager 1.30.15), R 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Installing package(s) 'DMRcate'
installing the source package ‘DMRcate’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.13/bioc/src/contrib/DMRcate_2.6.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 344226 bytes (336 KB)
downloaded 336 KB

* installing *source* package 'DMRcate' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: replacing previous import 'minfi::getMeth' by 'bsseq::getMeth' when loading 'DMRcate'
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICanno.ilm10b4.hg19'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'DMRcate'
* removing 'C:/Users/sainz/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/DMRcate'

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\sainz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpADMXbi\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In .inet_warning(msg) :
  installation of package ‘DMRcate’ had non-zero exit status
```

It says there is no package called "IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19".

Using suggestions from a similar question on StackOverflow, I tried to extract the source package from the temp location to the library location, but that gives the same error.

I'm doing this in Rstudio. I can't figure out what's missing here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The package name in the error is different than the one you are loading. The error says "IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICanno.ilm10b4.hg19" but you have "IlluminaHumanMethylation450kanno.ilmn12.hg19" installed. The "EPICanno.ilm10b4" part is different than the "450kanno.ilmn12" part. try running `BiocManager::install("IlluminaHumanMethylationEPICanno.ilm10b4.hg19")`

Comment: @MrFlick That was really stupid of me, thanks! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess the length of the package name is running over a path length limit on your OS (which looks like Windows).  You are trying to install into

`C:/Users/sainz/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/`

and might be able to work around the limit by putting the `Illumina...` package into a library with a shorter name, or maybe just installing it locally, instead of into OneDrive.